# Search function not working in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have huge data records in my table which I will be fetching from my database table and for that I will need search option to filter data.
the search function is not working.
When I enter any words in search box it does not show anything,neither it says record does not exist nor throws any error.
***Expected:***When user enters anything in search box,the record related with those words should be displayed.Please check the code and let me know how can I resolve it.

```
       <?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = 'contacts'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
 }

$sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM contact';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Displaying MySQL Data in HTML Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #343d44;
        font-family: "segoe-ui", "open-sans", tahoma, arial;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    table {
        margin: auto;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe Ui";
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}


#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

 #myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

    /* Table */
    .data-table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 537px;
    }

    .data-table th, 
    .data-table td {
        border: 1px solid #e1edff;
        padding: 7px 17px;
    }
    .data-table caption {
        margin: 7px;
    }

    /* Table Header */
    .data-table thead th {
        background-color: #508abb;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #6ea1cc !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    /* Table Body */
    .data-table tbody td {
        color: #353535;
    }
    .data-table tbody td:first-child,
    .data-table tbody td:nth-child(4),
    .data-table tbody td:last-child {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
        background-color: #f4fbff;
    }
    .data-table tbody tr:hover td {
        background-color: #ffffa2;
        border-color: #ffff0f;
    }

    /* Table Footer */
    .data-table tfoot th {
        background-color: #e5f5ff;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .data-table tfoot th:first-child {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .data-table tbody td:empty
    {
        background-color: #ffcccc;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<table class="data-table" id="example">
    <caption class="title">US Data</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ContactID</th>
            <th>ContactOwner</th>
            <th>LeadSource</th>
            <th>First_name</th>
            <th>Last_name</th>
            <th>AccountName</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>EmailID</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Industry</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Assistant</th>
            <th>AsstPhone</th>
            <th>ReportsTo</th>
            <th>LinkedIn</th>
            <th>CallStatus</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>OtherStreet</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $no     = 1;
    $total  = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['ContactID'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ContactOwner'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['LeadSource'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['First_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Last_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['AccountName'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['EmailID'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Department'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Industry'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Phone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Mobile'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Fax'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['DOB'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Assistant'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['AsstPhone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ReportsTo'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['LinkedIn'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['CallStatus'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Street'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['OtherStreet'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['City'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['State'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Zip'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Country'].'</td>    
                <td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>                    
            </tr>';

        $no++;
    }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("example");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
   if (td) {
  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
   } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }       
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need more information. Where is the code failing? Does it throw an error ?

Comment: @kawadhiya21: No,search option does not work.

Comment: "not working" is not an error message or a problem description. Do you get an error message in your browser console? Do you get some unexpected results? Provide a proper, detailed description of your issue. Describe what you expect to happen, and contrast it with what is actually happening. You can't just say "not working" and expect people to guess the problem. If you were a doctor and spoke to another doctor, would you say "this patient is ill", and give no further information to them? No, you'd describe your findings. So please do the same thing here, programmer-to-programmer.

Comment: @ADyson : I have updated the issue .It will be great help if you can check the code and help me resolve my issue.

Comment: "neither it says record does not exist nor throws any error. ". Why would you expect it to say "record does not exist"? You haven't written any code which would do that.

Comment: Please try to explain why your code should work?

Comment: @ADyson: Sir, I know that I have not written any code for such error message.But I have written about what I expect.Can you tell me if there is any error on script or code by which the search option is not working.

Comment: @Code4R7: "Why my code should work"- because I have written html table code and jscript to display the record related to entered text.

Comment: you can't say that you expect something to happen, when you already know you haven't written code for it, and it is therefore impossible. That's a bizarre statement IMO. If you want that feature, write it, it's not hard. If you thought you had created it but couldn't understand why it didn't work, then that's a different situation. Anyway, I am just composing a suitable answer which hopefully will fix the code you _have_ written. I will post it shortly.

Comment: @ADyson: Sure Sir, thanks for that in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement that it's "not working" is not strictly true. It does work, but only in limited circumstances. If you'd tested it thoroughly you could have provided this data in the question - that's what I meant by explaining the problem in detail and providing full information.

Anyway, there are a number of issues with the code.

1) It only ever searches the first column of any row (`getElementsByTagName("td")[0]` returns only the first column)

2) If any of your `<td>` elements were to contain further HTML for any reason, it would search the HTML tags as well. `innerHTML` should be replaced with `innerText` to avoid that.

3) Once you search through all columns, the simple if/else logic to show/hide the whole `<tr>` will fail because each time you loop through a column, it could cause the column to be hidden again, when the previous iteration had caused it to be shown. Instead, assume it will be hidden, and then only show it if there's at least one match to the search text within the columns.

4) I think once you get lots of rows you will get performance and usability problems because the search begins as soon as the user types a single character. If you type "s" and there are thousands of rows with thousands of cells, chances are 70% of them will contain "s" (in English, at least). It will slow down the system and provide no value to the user. I have written my example so that it doesn't start until the user enters 3 characters. You might want to provide some instructions to that effect in your finished product (or associated training materials).

Here is a working version, using some basic not-quite-random sample data. Note that the "example" ID is moved onto the `<tbody>` element, to avoid hiding the table header by accident.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  
  var table = document.getElementById("example");
  var trList = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
  for (i = 0; i < trList.length; i++)
  {
    //don't initiate search unless user types at least 3 characters. This will greatly improve performance and usability especially with large tables.
    if (filter.length >= 3)
    {
   var match = false;
      var tdList = trList[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

   //loop through every td
   for (j = 0; j < tdList.length; j++)
   {
     var td = tdList[j];

        if (td)
     {
          if (td.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      match = true;
          }
     }
      }
   
   if (match == true)
   {
        trList[i].style.display = "";
   }
   else
   {
  trList[i].style.display = "none";
   }
 }
    else
    {
      trList[i].style.display = "";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table class="data-table">
 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ContactID</th>
            <th>ContactOwner</th>
            <th>LeadSource</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="example">
  <tr>
   <td>Fish</td>
   <td>Fishing</td>
   <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Hello</td>
   <td>World</td>
   <td>Estate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Yellow</td>
   <td>Calling</td>
   <td>Bring</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is very well written.Also, you described it very briefly to make me understand what all is supposed to be enhanced to make it a working code.Thank you very much. I copied this code into my script but I don't know why it is not working with that.

Comment: well, I can't say because I don't know exactly how you have integrated it. But you should look for error messages etc in your console. It should simply have been a case of replacing your own "myFunction" content with this version, and also making the small change to the table id that I mentioned.